Is there a database or catalog of all black hole candidates?
I am searching for a catalog, list, database, etc. That should show astronomical observations of known black hole candidates. I am primarily interested in knowing the mass of these candidates.
I have found this paper: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016A%26A...587A..61C/abstract
but I am curious if more recent work is available or something more complete has been done. Ideally I'd like to get data on the ALL known black hole candidates in the universe, so both black holes in our own galaxy and black hole candidates that might be at the center of other galaxies.

I assume you've already seen this (and the links there)?

@josephh I have not see that, thank you. This does seem like a mixed bag with some showing theoretical limits and I am worried about using Wiki as a source, but I'm assuming the individual refs tie back to research papers? Thanks again, will be super helpful.

you're welcome. Good luck with it.

I would suggest [astronomy.se] as a good place to go for this sort of information.

Thanks @StephenG-HelpUkraine. Is there a way to migrate a question, or do I just need to repost it there? Cheers.

Wikipedia has also a more general list here. The paper you mentioned has a site that seems more updated here. In "Astronomy", you can check this similar question here.
